# How do I implement emoji picker in javascript with custom images?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an app where an option to stick images from an array of images is required just like in chat apps.
How do I do it in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should know: emoji is implemented as web fonts.

If you want to have customized icons, you may need to create your own font files(ex. ttf or wof files) and include them in your web site.

There is no limitation for one to implement by images, simply inefficiency.

Here is one of thousands articles you can read:
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Happy emoji!